# ASP.Net WebApi + Mvc =?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Just happened to hear about the latest in .NET Stack which combines both the functionality of ASP.NET Webapi and Mvc ?

The main functionality is to provide a simple and single routing architecture and everything. But didn't get the name of the tech outlined in TechEd. Googled to find none.

Any ideas ?

Comment: It's called ASP.NET MVC 6, ASP.NET 5 or currently goes by the name [ASP.NET vNext](http://www.asp.net/vnext)

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov: `ASP.NET vNext`, that's the word. Thank you :)

Comment: YuvalItzchakov / @Oluwafemi: Please consider posting an answer so I can accept and close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET vNEXT you can read all about it right here:

http://www.asp.net/vnext

https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/introducing-asp-net-5

http://www.infoq.com/news/2014/05/ASP.NET-vNext